# Using CanActivate in combination with redirect?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-router

It seems `CanActivate` cannot be used in combination with a redirect based on this [Stackblitz experiment](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-canactivatechild-withmodule?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

This is the snippet being tested.

```
{ path: 'module', loadChildren: 
'./module#ComponentModule'},
{ path: '', 
    pathMatch: 'full', 
    canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
    redirectTo: 'module' },
];
```

What I expected to happen is that before the Angular router actually completes the redirect it executes the `CanActivate` guard.

However it never executes.  This means we can't use `CanActivate` in combination with `redirect`.

The reason that would be useful is that if it worked Angular could still prefetch the module being guarded, yet it's guarded, so we won't allow access to it until the conditions of the guard pass.

I'd like to request that Angular refactor the router such that this works, but first I want to make sure that my interpretation of the current semantics is correct.

If I made any mistakes in my interpretation or setting up the demo please let me know.

[This is effectively the feature request.  Please vote for it if you like the concept](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27918)

Comment: Not sure but why don't you use authgaurd at the component level. Have tried but have a look:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-canactivatechild-withmodule-2v6n6p

Comment: @PrashantPimpale that is definitely doable.  The only drawback, IIUC, is that for example if we have an `AdminModule` with say 20 paths that are protected we now have to add the `AuthGuard` to all of the paths instead of just the path that directs to the module.

Comment: Yup....! got it

Comment: If you have an AdminModule with 20 paths then you can set the guard on top level and have child routes like:  path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
... and 20 more
If you really want something like your example you could create a custom guard that does the redirection

Comment: That is what it tries to do.  It sets the guard on the `redirect` and expects that the guard will be checked first.  This is the simplest solution.  There are a few ways of factoring around the missing capability,but it's more work.  I'm hoping Google will just fix it.  It used to work, but was disabled.

Comment: But the guard should be on the module self anyway because someone could just navigate to /module

Comment: Good point - So if we can use the guard on both the redirect and the lazy loaded module path, then we get the benefit of preloading the module without allowing access to it.

Comment: I wonder if something like `module/**/*` might be needed to guard all sub paths though?

Comment: If you guard .module all sub paths are automatically guarded too.

Comment: OK - That's what I was hoping - Cool!  So ideally if we can simply use `CanActivate` in combination with `loadChildren` then we should be able to prefetch the module without invoking any paths in it until the `CanActivate` guard passes.